# How to query array elements in mongo so that all nested items pass a given condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In Mongo I have data structure like this:

db.elements

```
{
  id: 1,
  arr: [
    {status: true},
    {status: false}
  ]
},

{
  id: 2,
  arr: [
    {status: true},
    {status: true}
  ]
}
```

I need to find items where status == true for all elements in arr.
I expect to see item with id==2.

BUT

```
db.elements.find({'arr.status': true})
```

will return both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform an `aggregate` to :

- `$unwind` your array
- `$group` by `$_id` and by `$arr.status`
- `$group` by `$_id` and build an array of all **distinct** values of `status` (so it will give you [true,false] or [true] or [false])
- `$match` all records that have the former array size == 1 && first element is `true`

mongo query is :

```
db.elements.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$arr"
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            id: "$id",
            value: "$arr.status"
        }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.id",
        value: {
            $addToSet: '$_id.value'
        }
    }
}, {
    "$match": {
        "value": {
            "$size": 1,
        },
        "value.0": true
    }
}]);
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/akinaru/c59fd94af1cebaa99d912b89f3634ba1) is a demo

Comment: Thank you! Just played around your example, my final query looks this way: 
*db.elements.aggregate([{ $unwind: '$arr' },{$group: { _id: '$id'
, status: {$addToSet: '$arr.status'}}},{$match: {'status':
{$size: 1}, 'status.0': true}}])*